# AWS cognito access from backend

Tags: python, amazon-cognito

I have created a sample congnito app and added few users, now i am trying to access the users from python code , but getting below error, i have developer access.  Please let me know how to get user details from cognito

code:
import boto3

```
   client = boto3.client('cognito-idp',region_name='us-east-2')
      response = client.admin_get_user(
           UserPoolId='us-east-2_XXXXXXX',
           Username='newuser'
          )
```

error:ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the AdminGetUser operation: The security token included in the request is expired

Comment: Does this help? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/security-token-expired/

Comment: @jellycsc, in my code i am not passing token parameters ..still its giving this error .. how to add the token in above code

Comment: admin_get_user is an admin call so tokens are not used here at all, unless you are using STS. Are you using STS?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad, no  i am not using sts ,, could please let me know how to use STS and get user details from cognito

Comment: You don't need to use token for admin get user. The only reason it would throw a token error would be if you were using STS to authenticate your "admin" account. Please check if the error is being thrown by this line of code or some other line. Also mention where you are running this (locally or on lambda)

Comment: @NinadGaikwad, i am running locally .. i can get user details using list_user option but when i try with admin its not working

Comment: How are you passing IAM access key and secret key?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad,  i am able to get users by passing key and secret in client. now i want to fetch all the users using created date attribute .. but client.list_users method is not accepting created date as a filter parameter..

Comment: Make a new question. And post the code you are using there. Comment and let me know once you post the question, I'll try to help.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad, below is the link for new question ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62655263/how-to-get-list-of-users-based-on-created-date-updated-date-from-cognito