# how to get list of users based on created date/updated date from cognito

Tags: python, amazon-cognito

I am trying to fetch users from cognito with sub and created date , able to fetch the user using sub but its not accepting for created date, as this is not attribute to pass for filter, below is the code for the same , i wan to pass created in filter Filter="created ="2020-06-30""

```
 import boto3

 client = boto3.client('cognito-idp',region_name='us-east-2',
                     aws_access_key_id='XXXXXX',
                     aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXX',
                     )

  response1 = client.list_users(UserPoolId='us-east-2_XXXXXX',AttributesToGet= 
  ['birthdate','name','sub'], Filter="sub =\"XXXXX-dCCa-4121-94c9-XXXXXX\"")

  print(response1)
```

error:
InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the ListUsers operation: Invalid search attribute: UserCreateDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html):

> You can only search for the following standard attributes:
>
> - username (case-sensitive)
> - email
> - phone_number
> - name
> - given_name
> - family_name
> - preferred_username
> - cognito:user_status (called Status in the Console) (case-insensitive)
> - status (called Enabled in the Console) (case-sensitive)
> - sub

You can write your own code to filter the results you get from list_users. Run a loop on the USERS value that is returned and create a new list with only users matching your filter criteria for date.

Comment: yes i tried to get the user with above approach but not able compare date format with , in cognito updated date format is different ..not sure how to compare with current date.'UserCreateDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 29, 22, 27, 5, 149000, tzinfo = tzlocal())

Comment: datetime is a library is python. Just import datetime and assign this datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 29, 22, 27, 5, 149000, tzinfo = tzlocal()) to a variable.

Comment: Please mark answer as correct and upvote if it solved your issue

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you please check below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663272/variable-format-for-filter-in-cognito