# variable format for filter in cognito

Tags: python, amazon-cognito

i am trying to get user details from cognito based on sub id, below is code for the same(Filter="sub ="XXXXX-dCCa-4121-94c9-XXXXXX""), now i want to pass the variable in filter , tried with below format but its not working, what is the exact format to pass variable in filter,

code : import boto3

```
  client = boto3.client('cognito-idp',region_name='us-east-2',
                 aws_access_key_id='XXXXXX',
                 aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXX',
                 )
   id='XXXXX-dCCa-4121-94c9-XXXXXX'
 response1 = client.list_users(UserPoolId='us-east-2_XXXXXX',AttributesToGet= 
 ['birthdate','name','sub'], Filter="sub = \"" + id + "\"")
 print(response1)
```

Comment: This is the correct format. I recreated this code locally and it worked for the test user i created. Are you getting an error?

Comment: @NinadGaikwad, yes i am getting error in Jupiter notebook, but its working fine in .py file .. issue with Jupiter notebook i think..